ルート案内実行時に「DIRECTIONS_ROUTE: UNKNOWN_ERROR: There was an issue performing a Directions request.」となる
Googleマップを表示するために WPF アプリケーション内に HTML を埋め込んでいます。
2地点間のルート案内を実行しようとすると、次のエラーが発生し、正しく表示されません
" MapsServerError: DIRECTIONS_ROUTE: UNKNOWN_ERROR: There was an issue performing a Directions request."
以下、エラー名で検索して私が試したことです。

API キーを検証しました: Google マップ API キーが正しいことを確認しました。
API クォータを確認しました: API 使用制限に達していないことを確認しました。
問題は最初に発生してから数日間改善されていません。

このエラーメッセージの具体的な原因をご存知でしょうか？
どうすれば修正して防止できますか?
正常に動作する場合もあり、以下は正常に動作するときのコードを添付します。
例えば、test18変数を追加すると、タイトルが示すようにエラーが発生します。
コードの桁数が影響を与えることがあるのでしょうか？
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body,
        div {
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script defer
            async
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";

        window.addEventListener("load", onInitialized, false);

        const MAPS_GOOGLE_COM_URL = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js";

        const MSG_ON_INITIALIZED = 0x00000001;

        const CONST_TRAVEL_MODE_DRIVING = 0;
        const CONST_TRAVEL_MODE_BICYCLING = 1;
        const CONST_TRAVEL_MODE_TRANSIT = 2;
        const CONST_TRAVEL_MODE_WALKING = 3;
        let map;
        let directionsService;

        const test1 = null;
        const test2 = null;
        const test3 = null;
        const test4 = null;
        const test5 = null;
        const test6 = null;
        const test7 = null;
        const test8 = null;
        const test9 = null;
        const test10 = null;
        const test11 = null;
        const test12 = null;
        const test13 = null;
        const test14 = null;
        const test15 = null;
        const test16 = null;
        const test17 = null;

        /**
         * GoogleMap controller
         */
        let googleMapInstance = null;

        /**
         * Retain marker information
         */
        let markerInfos = [];

        /**
         * For drawing route guidance.
         */
        let directionsRenderer = null;

        /**
         * Check if object is usable
         */
        function hasObject(obj) {
            return obj !== undefined && obj !== null;
        }

        /**
         * Send JSON to CefSharp side.
         */
        function sendMessage(what, data) {
            const msg = {
                what: what,
                data: data,
            };

            CefSharp.PostMessage(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }

        function initMap() {
            // Initial map settings
            const tokyoStation = { lat: 35.681167, lng: 139.767052 }; // Tokyo station coordinates
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: tokyoStation
            });

            // Initializing the Directions service and renderer
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

            // Show directions
            displayRoute(new google.maps.LatLng(35.681167, 139.767052), new google.maps.LatLng(35.54850587440997, 139.77800582433392));
        }

        function displayRoute(origin, destination) {
            const request = {
                origin: origin,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
                } else {
                    console.error('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                    alert('Directions request failed: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
        
        /**
         * Convert to LatLng object for Google Map.
         * 
         * @param position
         */
        function toGoogleMapLatLng(position) {
            return new google.maps.LatLng({
                lat: position.lat,
                lng: position.lng,
            });
        }

        /**
         * Zoom level change request
         *
         */
        function requestChangeZoomLevel(data) {
            if (!hasObject(googleMapInstance)) {
                // GoogleMapインスタンスが無いときは何もしない
                return;
            }

            googleMapInstance.setZoom(data.zoomLevel);
        }
        /**
         * Called when page initialization is complete.
         */
        function onInitialized() {
            sendMessage(MSG_ON_INITIALIZED, null);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>

